# TListView OnCustomDrawItem behaviour changed in 10.2 Update 3

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.2-tokyo, tlistview

I have a TListView in which I want to display one particular row with **bold** text. To that end, I created an OnCustomDrawItem handler like so:

```
procedure TDataDirHandlingDlg.lvDataFoldersCustomDrawItem(
  Sender: TCustomListView;
  Item: TListItem;
  State: TCustomDrawState;
  var DefaultDraw: Boolean);
begin
  case GetItemStatus(Item.Data) of
    ddNonExistent:
      begin
        Sender.Canvas.Font.Color := clGrayText;
        Sender.Canvas.Font.Style := [];
      end;
    ddCurrent:
      begin
        Sender.Canvas.Font.Style := [fsBold];
        Sender.Canvas.Font.Color := clBlue;
      end;
  else
    begin
      Sender.Canvas.Font.Color := clWindowText;
      Sender.Canvas.Font.Style := [];
    end;
  end;
end;
```

(Background information: it's a list of certain directories and their properties. Exactly one directory can be "Current" and that's the one that I want to emphasize. GetStatusItem returns an enum value which is either of ddOK, ddNonExistent, or ddCurrent).

This worked as I expected using Delphi 10.2 ("Tokyo") Update 2 **but does not work using Update 3**. To be more specific, the font color still works. But the font style does not.

I can see in the VCL source code that Vcl.ComCtrls.pas has changed from Update 2 to Update 3 in TCustomListView.CNNotify, and a SaveDC/RestoreDC call has been removed in Update 3. I guess it is relevant but I haven't yet managed to understand the code.

As you can see I make no attempt to actually draw the text in the handler. I just change the properties of the canvas.

The question is: **is it sheer luck that the code worked in Update 2?** Do I have to draw the text myself, or should it be enough to modify the canvas and let VCL continue with drawing the text? If so, why doesn't it work in Update 3?

Comment: I don't have Tokyo installed, so can't check/compare the sources. What you have done should be right, when you only want to set font color and style. You could try what happens if you draw the text yourself at the end and set `DefaultDraw` to false.

Comment: `TListView` has always suffered from faulty drawing handling. Going all the way back to D6, I was struggling with issues related to custom-drawing. In one app, where I use `OnAdvancedCustomDrawItem` and `OnAdvancedCustomDrawSubItem`, I had to resort to manually triggering the `Canvas.Font.OnChange` event after making changes, so it wouldn't report back to Windows correctly. Sad to hear that after all these years, `TListView` still has drawing problems.

Comment: This report may relate to your problem: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-20231

Comment: Thanks - RSP--20231 must indeed be the same problem. Let's hope they will fix it then...

Comment: +1, just hit the same problem - workaround would be great, in desperation tried Remy's Font.onChange() , does not work